# How to disable clickable area with clickable area inside

Tags: html

It's possible to disable the "ONE" area when I click in the "TWO" area ?

```js
   <div className="bg-orange-700 w-20 h-20" onClick={() => console.log('ONE')}>
      <div className="bg-yellow-400 w-10 h-10" onClick={() => console.log('TWO')} />
    </div>
```

Comment: what does 'disable' mean to you? Not clickable?

Comment: which framework? if react, which type of component? need more info.

Comment: No, i want to click on "TWO" area without activate the onClick on "ONE" area

Comment: I use react with functional component

Comment: and which css framework are you using?

Comment: it is tailwind but I think it is not usefull

Comment: i know, i was trying to re-create your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `e.stopPropagation();`

```
<div className="bg-orange-700 w-20 h-20" onClick={() => console.log('ONE')}>
      <div className="bg-yellow-400 w-10 h-10" 
           onClick={(e) => {
               e.stopPropagation(); 
               console.log('TWO');
           }} />
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I have tried but not correctly